# Indexes in Oracle

Tags: oracle, indexing

As always, I apologize if this is a stupid question (two questions, actually). I'm not a DBA, so I know very little about indexes. My questions are:

1. Is there any cutoff point (in terms of number of rows) at which an index would be pointless? For example, is there any benefit to an index on a lookup table with 10-20 rows?
2. I've read some things about covering indexes in Oracle, and the concept makes sense in that the data can be retrieved directly from the index and a trip to the table is unnecessary. How can I tell if an index is a covering index? Is this a value set when the index is created, or by default based on the rows that the index includes?

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Richard Foote has a series of blog posts on [indexes for small tables](http://richardfoote.wordpress.com/2009/04/16/indexes-on-small-tables-part-i-one-of-the-few/).  The short answer is probably not (but the long answer is much more interesting).

A covering index is a general term for an index that contains all the columns that are part of either the SELECT list or the WHERE clause for a table.  It is not a property of an index-- any index can be a covering index for some query.  It is something that is specific to a query and to the indexes available to the optimizer.

Answer (score 3):

1. Small tables can be created as an "indexed oriented table" in which case the table and the index are the same "object" in storage. I believe a primary key is required for an IOT. Before IOTs were available it was in many cases a judgement call. Certainly, if the index was almost as big or bigger than the table it's useless unless it's being used to enforce uniqueness.

   [another Richard Foote link](http://richardfoote.wordpress.com/2009/05/27/indexes-and-small-tables-part-vii-cluster-one/)
2. You have to look at the query being run and compare it to the index. An index on `(A, B)` covers:

   select B from T where A = 3